# How do you know the exit status of commands in cisco switch?

Tags: cisco

In Unix, if we do `echo $?`, it shows the status of the last command executed.

Where `$?` holds the value 0 or 1:

- 0 implies success
- 1 implies failure

But how can we know the status of a command executed in a Cisco switch?

Comment: Nitpick: `$?` can hold other values too, all non-zero values indicate a failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cisco device, if it provides no output error, it was successful. If any error occurs, It will show the details of where is your mistake in the command, mark by the caret symbol - "^" - under the character you were wrong.

Another note, in Unix, any return code that not equal zero means that the command failed.